# Why is Flutter building without sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

My `pubspec.yaml` has

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.15.0-116.0.dev <3.0.0'
```

When I run

```
flutter build appbundle/apk
```

it prints

```
Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              8.8s
```

**Note:** I have not opted out of null safety by using any of the workarounds. My entire project is 100% sound null safe. I'm also not looking for ways on how to build apk with sound null safety. The question is why is it printing `Building without sound null safety` when everything is setup correctly.

---

**What I've tried:**

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Restarted the editor, etc.

Running

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

prints

```
Showing dependencies that are currently not opted in to null-safety.
[✗] indicates versions without null safety support.
[✓] indicates versions opting in to null safety.

Package Name  Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies: all support null safety.

dev_dependencies: all support null safety.
All dependencies opt in to null-safety.
```

Comment: did you check your packages. they might not be null safety.

Comment: @Eray I've updated my post. You can see all packages are null safe

Comment: and what happens if you use `--sound-null-safety`? does `--verbose` add some interesting logs?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it works. It shows ` Building with sound null safety `. Can you tell me if I've accidentally added some flags in my code, because `flutter build apk` should also print this.

Comment: i dont know, its strange to be honest that it does not show   by default...

Comment: I'm confused.  You requested `--no-sound-null-safety` and then seem confused by getting a message about "Building without sound null safety"?  Why are you using `--no-sound-null-safety`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Actually a user posted an answer with this flag, so I updated my post with this flag too. I've removed it now. But again the question is why `flutter build apk` is not running with sound null safety.

Comment: @pskink I'm so sorry, I just found that one file was using `// @dart=2.9` (opting out). I removed that line and now my code is working fine.

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry it was my mistake. One of my files had opted-out. Sorry if this has wasted some of your time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologize. It was my blunder.

One of my files was opted-out of null safety as I was using

```
// @dart=2.9
```

Once I removed it, the build started working again with null safety.